# How to access an instance variables id in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using carrierwave to upload photos into my app, the photos have a 'belongs_to' relationship with each location, and the location has a 'has_many' relationship to the photos. Im my show page where the photos for the locations are uploaded they display as normal through a loop. However, in my index page I'm looping through my locations and want to display a photo for that location. The photos have the correct location_id, I'm just not sure on the syntax in the view to access that locations photo. What I would like to do is display one of the photos that correlates to a specific location, something like: @photo(location.id.last). Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

View

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- featured listings gallery -->
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <% if location.featured == "true" %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="overlay">
            <%= image_tag @photos, :size => '400x300', :class => 'img-responsive' %>
            <div class="effect">
              <div class="overlay-header">
                <%= location.name %>
              </div>
              <div class="location-link">
                <%= link_to "View Building", location_path(location) %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="display-box-caption">
            <%= truncate(location.description, length: 100) %><%= link_to 'More', location_path(location), :class => 'more-info'  %>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 property-link-container">
          <%= link_to "View Building", location_path(location), :class=>"property-link" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @locations = Location.all
  @photos = Photo.all
end
def about

end
def faqs

end
def blog

end
def whats_included

end
```

end

Comment: You can access one photo per location like this: `<%= location.photos.last.id %>`(this will give you id of the last photo) and if just do  `<%= location.photos.last %>`(it will give you the photo object itself), as you have already defined the association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing photo with the help of association:

```
location.photos.last.photo.url
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- featured listings gallery -->
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <% if location.featured == "true" %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="overlay">
            <!-- changing @photos to location.photos.last -->
            <% if location.photos.any? and location.photos.photo.present? %>
              <%= image_tag location.photos.last.photo.url, :size => '400x300', :class => 'img-responsive' %>
            <% end %>
            <div class="effect">
              <div class="overlay-header">
                <%= location.name %>
              </div>
              <div class="location-link">
                <%= link_to "View Building", location_path(location) %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="display-box-caption">
            <%= truncate(location.description, length: 100) %><%= link_to 'More', location_path(location), :class => 'more-info'  %>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 property-link-container">
          <%= link_to "View Building", location_path(location), :class=>"property-link" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.all
  # no need to fetch photos now
  # @photos = Photo.all
end
```

Photo Model

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :location
 mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

Comment: This seams close, its giving me the images memory location: <photo:0xb542a288> and an image icon.

Comment: You can call `.url` on `location.photos.last`, so it will be like, `location.photos.last.url`. Can you also post `photo.rb` model code in your question?

Comment: undefined method `url' for #<Photo:0xb52ba024>

Comment: I did, it says awaiting peer review.

Comment: This worked! Awesome, could you briefly explain? Also, how can I avoid an error when uploading a new location, before it has a photo? This is done in the show view after the location has been created.

Comment: When you define mount_upload in `photo.rb`, you give a reference name to the photos that will be uploaded. In your case you called it as `photo`(You can rename it as anything like `image`, so that you don't get confused). So to get the photo url one has to call the `photo.url` method on the photo object. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord-1).

Comment: Please check the if condition that I have added to check if the images are already present or not.

Comment: It didn't, undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Updated now, `<% if location.photos.any? %>` this checks if the photos are present or not. Read [this](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/3096503536/how-to-check-if-objects-or-relations-exist) more information on when to use `present?` and `any?`.

Comment: not sure why, its erroring out: undefined method `photo' for #<Location:0xb940a6a0>

Comment: can u give a print statement inside the if condition, just to check if it is still going inside. If it still goes inside then you can add, `<% if location.photos.any? and location.photos.photo.present? %>`. This check is needed whenever you are creating a new location or there are no photos right?

Comment: The if condition that is present in your code is partial, please change it to this, `<% if location.photos.any? and location.photos.photo.present? %>` (this if for checking if there any photos and if a photo exists does it have a photo actually stored using carrierwave).

Comment: <% if location.photos.any? %> worked! Thank you for all your effort, I needed to command+r reset. I was anxious and rushed through it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I see Sahil's post helped. Add `.includes(:photos)`, to load Queries faster. In the future, will be super useful.

```
def index
  @locations = Location.includes(:photos).all
end
```

Comment: Yes this is better for querying faster, I think it should be `:photos` and not `:photo` as location has many photos.